# jquery replace string in url images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

please help me
    how to replace string url image from s120

**s120**/demo%2Bproduct%2Blipstik.jpg

to

**s400**/demo%2Bproduct%2Blipstik.jpg

```
//jQuery
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#largeimage").click(function(){
        $(".container img").attr("src").replace("s120","s400");
    });
});
```

html

```
<div class="container center">
  <img src="https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-NwKHFcL48ZA/WJ2FANm2TXI/AAAAAAAAA6Y/hE-85KroGacBYy26mnEbkEGYFcnyWWv4gCLcB/s120/demo%2Bproduct%2Blipstik.jpg">
</div>
<p>
<button class="center" id="largeimage">Large Image to 400</button>
</p>
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/wy5wnxqu/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not updating the attribute, do it using a callback with [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function) method which holds the old value as the second argument.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#largeimage").click(function() {
    $(".container img").attr("src", function(i, src) {
      return src.replace("s120", "s400");
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach - changing `img` src inside the `attr` function.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#largeimage").click(function(){
     var src = $(".container img").attr("src");
     $(".container img").attr("src", src.replace("s120","s400"));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container center">
  <img src="https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-NwKHFcL48ZA/WJ2FANm2TXI/AAAAAAAAA6Y/hE-85KroGacBYy26mnEbkEGYFcnyWWv4gCLcB/s120/demo%2Bproduct%2Blipstik.jpg">
</div>
<p>
<button class="center" id="largeimage">Large Image to 400</button>
</p>
```